# How can I know that App info screen of My Application is opened

Tags: android, permissions, settings, overlay

When App info screen of my Android application is opened in Settings screen, Need to draw overlay screen on top of app info screen.
How can I know that App info screen of My Application is opened. Do we get any callback when app info screen is opened.
ex: settings -> apps -> MyApp [Requirement is to draw overlay on this screen of my app]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Do we get any callback when app info screen is opened. ex: settings -> apps -> MyApp

No, sorry.

> Need to draw overlay screen on top of app info screen

I sincerely hope that this proves to be impossible, for security reasons. Users need to be able to uninstall the app, clear data, adjust permissions, control notification behavior, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can tell if the user is in your app info screen, you can monitor some of the settings windows though.
Do note that it's no longer possible to draw over any system component, I don't recall since which version of android, but it's been like this for a while, I think since Android 7.0 or so, therefore, you can't prevent the user from clicking anywhere they wish, as long as they are viewing a system ui (such as settings app, status bar and etc)